# Algorithm to find the most adequate location compromise for several travellers

Tags: algorithm, geolocation

I have been wondering for quite a while now if there was an already known algorithm solving the following problem or, at least, part of it.

Let's say there are a finite set of locations (x,y) and each of those locations have also a type (house, restaurant, café, cinéma...) and a weight (user rating, quality/price ratio ...). Moreover, there is a subset of paths faster than others (depending on the transportation type and the desired time of arrival).

The kind of question to answer: we are a group of people all located at n different locations, we wanna meet at time T, find us the best location (minimizing each's path length and travel time) of type t (cinema...).

Does that sound like any known algorithm?

Best regards,
Rolf

Comment: I chose here cartesian coordinates, at least for start, as I don't envisage to implement this in a large network. This wouldn't work for people dispatched all over the world, of course.

Comment: As long as you enjoy kayaking, it is possible to extend this all over the world. :)

Comment: Héhé :-) But cartesian coordinates and euclidian geometry wouldn't be a good fit to compute distances on the globe (as far as I remember from my distant math lessons) :P

Comment: That is right, but this is the simplest problem to solve. You need some geodesic distance, see http://www.ga.gov.au/earth-monitoring/geodesy/geodetic-techniques/distance-calculation-algorithms.html.

Comment: Very clear contents, thanks for sharing. One potential problem now solved :)

Comment: Having P people and L (x,y) locations, you seem to be able to calculate `goTime[i,j] = calcTravel(Pi,Lj,T)`, being `O(P.L.a)` *a* being the algo (like Djikstra) - while eliminating all *goTime* that don't satisfy the *T* constraint. Then calculate the `interest[j]` for each L. Define a function `weight(goTime, interest)` based on subjective criteria, minimizing *time*, max *interest*. Take the *best* value... A too simplistic approach? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several algorithms to solve this problem, this problem is known as Facility Location or k center problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facility_location it's a NP Hard problem and there are some algorithms that aproximate solutions, also search for "Optimal meeting point" problem that it's used in spacial databases.